# Is it possible to get an array of Dropdown boxes with jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

I would like all dropdown boxes in a div to have the same dynamic options

This works fine for one Dropdown list

```
var ddl = $("#ddl_candidate_id");
for (k = 0; k < fileDetails.Headers.length; k++) {
    ddl.append("<option value='" + fileDetails.Headers[k] + "'>" + fileDetails.Headers[k] + "</option>");
```

but if I try and use a selector the code iterates through just as I expect it to but I guess

```
var dropdowns = $('.selectMapping');
```

is not strongly typed as a select (drop down)

```
var dropdowns = $('.selectMapping');
for (ov = 0; ov < fileDetails.Headers.length; ov++) {
    for (dd = 0; dd < dropdowns.length; dd++) {
        dropdowns[dd].append("<option value='" + fileDetails.Headers[ov] + "'>" + fileDetails.Headers[ov] + "</option>");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Carsten for the edit I was just doing that

Comment: Also, add: `console.log($(".selectMapping").length)` - if it's zero (0) then your selector isn't finding them - we can't help with that other than speculating unless you include some html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to loop through a jquery collection as `.append` will apply to all elements in the collection

```
var ddls = $(".select_class");
for (k = 0; k < fileDetails.Headers.length; k++) {
    ddls.append("<option value='" + fileDetails.Headers[k] + "'>" + fileDetails.Headers[k] + "</option>");
}
```

```js
var ddl = $("select");
for (k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
  ddl.append("<option value='" + k + "'>" + k + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
<select></select>
<select></select>
```

---

Regarding why your code was not working: Your issue is with `dropdowns[dd].append(` as that is no longer a jquery collection. `$("select")[0]` will give a DOM element.

You want `.eq(dd)` instead of `[dd]` then your dd loop will work.

```
var dropdowns = $('.selectMapping');
for (ov = 0; ov < fileDetails.Headers.length; ov++) {
    for (dd = 0; dd < dropdowns.length; dd++) {
        dropdowns.eq(dd).append("<option value='" + fileDetails.Headers[ov] + "'>" + fileDetails.Headers[ov] + "</option>");
    }
}
```

*as noted above, there's no need for this in this scenario, but it completes the issue raised in the question, this may be relevant for a different scenario*